# cfhoststartinforesolution fails. get device name from IP address on LAN

Tags: ios, iphone, network-programming

As a part of assignment I have to scan my LAN and get the names of devices connected to wifi.  I went through apples documentation [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/ResolvingDNSHostnames.html) and many other S.O links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992989/how-to-get-the-other-devices-host-name-in-the-same-wifi). However resolution is not happening, some error occurs. I am not a networking guy and hence most of it sounded greek to me. an almost same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407309/cfhoststartinforesolution-always-fail-ubunteros)
This is my code. I have written down the error that is occurring in comments.

An alternate answer would be helpful too.

```
+ (NSArray *)hostnamesForAddress:(NSString *)address {
// Get the host reference for the given address.
CFStreamError streamError;
struct addrinfo      hints;
struct addrinfo      *result = NULL;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_flags    = AI_NUMERICHOST;
hints.ai_family   = PF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;
int errorStatus = getaddrinfo([address cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, &hints, &result);
if (errorStatus != 0) return nil;
CFDataRef addressRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
if (addressRef == nil) return nil;
freeaddrinfo(result);
CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, addressRef);
if (hostRef == nil) return nil;
CFRelease(addressRef);
BOOL isSuccess = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, &streamError);
// always false
if (!isSuccess){
    NSLog(@"error:%@",[self convertCFStreamErrorIntoNSError:streamError]);
    // error:Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1cd29190 {kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
    return nil;
}

// Get the hostnames for the host reference.
CFArrayRef hostnamesRef = CFHostGetNames(hostRef, NULL);
NSMutableArray *hostnames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < [(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef count]; currentIndex++) {
    [hostnames addObject:[(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
}

return hostnames[0];
```

}

Comment: Did you get any success?

Comment: Nope. Do post the answer if u r able to solve this issue

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Nope. All hopes lost :(

Comment: I also encounter this issue. My stream Error is (CFStreamError) streamError = (domain = 12, error = 8)

Comment: @SonuVR any Success

Comment: @vaisakh nope. Are you trying to implement a network scanner ?

Comment: @SonuVR Yes, i am facing some issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463996/get-host-name-from-ip-address-ios-10